# Controlling a rich:togglePanel with a select widget

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262153) I tried the following

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="branchSelect" value="#{cloner.branchType}">
    <a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true" rerender="branchSelect, branchPanel" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Constant" itemValue="constant" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Pattern" itemValue="pattern" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<rich:togglePanel id="branchPanel" value="#{cloner.branchType}" switchType="ajax"
        initialState="constant">
    <f:facet name="constant">
        <h:outputText value="Some block specific to Constant option" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="pattern">
        <h:outputText value="Some block specific to Pattern option" />
    </f:facet>
</rich:togglePanel>
```

Of course my backing bean has a setter/getter for branchType, and I can see that branchType is indeed being set when the select is changed. The toggle panel just isn't changing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enclosing it within an `<h:form>` ?

anyway is `reRender` and not `rerender`

I'm trying to reRender the togglePanel and it does not work, I can't understand why. I've tried to enclose it into several things and tried to reRender them and nothing, it's only rendered when the page loads.